# return KEYS without the set

Tags: redis

I got a folder (I believe you call it a Set) in my Redis database named "g", where I store some keys.

```
KEYS *g:*
```

Returns

```
g: wasted
g: two
g: hours
g: with
g: this
```

**First question:** How can I make the query so I get the results below?

```
wasted
two
hours
with
this
```

"wasted","two","hours","with" and "this" are documents (I believe you call them keys?) with two columns and 100 rows inside. "Wasted" contains this:

```
 Hash Key      Hash Value 
 I             Myself
 Am            ToBe
 So            TooMuch
 Wasted        Wasted
```

**Second question:** How do I make a query to retrieve all keys and values?

I got a temp solution by replicating data. I created a folder, inserted just strings inside (I believe you call them hashes), and I just iterate over that folder/set and return each key one by one. But for production we would have to replicate 2TB of data, and that we cannot do.

Comment: Don't use "KEYS". Keys will iterate *ALL* the keys in your database, even those not starting with g:. As Itamar says, use SETS.

Answer (score 0):

WRT question 1: you should really learn about Redis' different [data structures](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), but from the looks of it you're not using a Set but rather just setting keys with a common prefix. To use a Set, you'll need to call [`SADD`](http://redis.io/commands/sadd), e.g.:

```
SADD g wasted two hours with this
```

Each of the "documents" is a member is the set, and calling [`SMEMBERS`](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) on it will return them.

WRT question 2: assuming you are asking how to get all the fields and their respective values from a Hash, use [`HGETALL`](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall).

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/mcnbja4s7/ . If I do KEYS *Groups:* the result doesn't satisfy me. The first result is "Groups:TheRedGroup" and since I only need to get "TheRedGroup", the only (terrible) solution seems to edit every string programatically in real time, in the server, and take "Groups:" from every group. What I'm asking is how to retrieve just the group names in the Redis Query without resorting to create a "grouplist" document and replicate every group name. Thanks for trying anyway, maybe I didn't explain myself.